# ionic - How to create small icon inside sidemenu?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I got a design from client. I want to embed small icon inside my sidemenu.

My current code

```
<ion-side-menus>

  <ion-pane ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable nav-title-slide-ios7">
      <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear"><i class="icon ion-ios7-arrow-back"></i> Back</ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-pane>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <header class="bar bar-header bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">Menu</h1>
    </header>
    <ion-content class="has-header">
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/home">
          Home
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/profile">
          Profile
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/friend">
          Friends
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/setting">
          Setting
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/shop">
          Shop
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

My objective

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I already got the answer

```
<ion-side-menus>

  <ion-pane ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable nav-title-slide-ios7">
      <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear"><i class="icon ion-ios7-arrow-back"></i> Back</ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-pane>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <header class="bar bar-header bar-stable">
    </header>
    <ion-content class="has-header mymenu">
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/home">
            <img src="img/home.png" width="30" />Home </ion-item>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/profile">
            <img src="img/profile.png" width="30" />Profile </ion-item>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/friend">
          <img src="img/friend.png" width="30" ng-click="friend()"/>Friends
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/setting">
          <img src="img/setting.png" width="30" />Setting
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/shop">
          <img src="img/shop.png" width="30" ng-click="shop()"/>Shop
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, for me if the image is too big I cannot get my text to align in the middle vertically. Do you have any solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

All you have to do is add the icon that you want in the same  as the text.  Here is an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/KIErTU?p=preview

```
<ion-item>
    <i class='ion-checkmark-circled'></i>home
</ion-item>
```

Nothing pretty, but it shows the point.

Answer (score 3):

```
<ion-item menu-close class="item-icon-left">
  <i class="icon ion-home" ></i>
  Home
</ion-item>
```

Add class `item-icon-left`to `ion-item` to nicely style and align the icons.

Answer (score 3):

Here is How You can so it while keeping ionic sidemenu intact.
This is for ionic 2:-

app.component.js

```
  pages: Array<{
      title: string, 
      component: any , 
      icon: string, 
      class: string
  }>;

  constructor(public platform: Platform, public statusBar: StatusBar, public splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    this.initializeApp();

    // used for an example of ngFor and navigation
    this.pages = [
      { 
        title: 'Home', 
        component: HomePage , 
        icon: '<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>' , 
        class: 'class1' 
      },
      { 
        title: 'List', 
        component: ListPage , 
        icon: '<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>' , 
        class: 'class2' 
      },
      { 
        title: 'Login Page', 
        component: LoginPage , 
        icon: '<i class="fa fa-book"></i>' , 
        class: 'class3' 
      }
    ];

  }
```

app.html:-

```
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button [ngClass]="p.class" menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
        <span class="menu_item_icon" [innerHTML]="p.icon"></span>
        <span class="menu_item_title">
            {{p.title}}
        </span>

      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
```

I used the ionic default boilerplate that contains the sidemenu.

Am new to Angular2. But I like doing things the clean way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use what Afflicted suggested but the following solution I used has a correct outlining:

```
<div class="list">

<a class="item item-icon-left" href="#">
  <i class="icon ion-email"></i>
  Check mail
</a>

...
```

[List icons in ionic](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#item-icons)